# How to reverse a string that contains surrogate pairs

Tags: c#, string, reverse, utf-16, surrogate-pairs

I have written this method to reverse a string

```
public string Reverse(string s)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) 
                return s;

            TextElementEnumerator enumerator =
               StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s);

            var elements = new List<char>();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var cs = enumerator.GetTextElement().ToCharArray();
                if (cs.Length > 1)
                {
                    elements.AddRange(cs.Reverse());
                }
                else
                {
                    elements.AddRange(cs);
                }
            }

            elements.Reverse();
            return string.Concat(elements);
        }
```

Now, I don't want to start a discussion about how this code could be made more efficient or how there are one liners that I could use instead.  I'm aware that you can perform Xors and all sorts of other things to potentially improve this code.  If I want to refactor the code later I could do that easily as I have unit tests.

Currently, this correctly reverses BML strings (including strings with accents like `"Les Misérables"`) and strings that contain combined characters such as `"Les Mise\u0301rables"`.

My test that contains surrogate pairs work if they are expressed like this

```
Assert.AreEqual("", _stringOperations.Reverse(""));
```

But if I express surrogate pairs like this

```
Assert.AreEqual("\u10000", _stringOperations.Reverse("\u10000"));
```

then the test fails.  Is there an air-tight implementation that supports surrogate pairs as well?

If I have made any mistake above then please do point this out as I'm no Unicode expert.

Comment: looks like c# supports only \u digit digit digit digit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: so maybe you're looking for "\U00010000"

Comment: That does seem to work but it goes into the if (cs.Length > 1) branch which suggests to me that this might be a different Unicode character to \u10000.  The branch that it goes into is for composite characters, so it's probably a different character. Either way there still is a set of strings that can't be reversed using this method.  We need a Unicode and C# expert to clear this all up.

Comment: I'm not really doing this for any particular purpose or project.  I'm writing this code out of curiosity and so when I try to reverse \u10000 I don't actually care what it prints, I just want to correctly reverse it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\u10000` is a string of two characters: [`က`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1000/index.htm) (Unicode code point 1000) followed by a `0` (which can be detected by inspecting the value of `s` in your method). If you reverse two characters, they won't match the input anymore.

It seems you're after [Unicode Character 'LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A' (U+10000)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10000/index.htm) with hexadecimal code point 10000. From [Unicode character escape sequences on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx):

> *\u   hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit*
>
> *\U   hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit*

So you'll have to use either four or eight digits.

Use `\U00010000` (notice the capital U) or `\uD800\uDC00` instead of `\u10000`.

Comment: Okay, you are right (+1), the unit tests for \U00010000 and \uD800\uDC00 both pass.  This is great.  But, the issue still stands "\u10000" is a valid string, yet it cannot be reversed using the method above?  So, 1. Why is this?  2.  What's the solution?

Comment: I think I answered that in my first two sentences. If you reverse two different characters (`AB` -> `BA`), then they don't match anymore. This means your reversion works, but you need to test whether the string has been reversed, not whether it matches the original input.

Comment: But they form a single character when combined in this way right?  Which means that a user would expect them to be reversed in such a way that the character, though made up of two different characters, would be reversed in it's entirety.  Therefore there must be a way of detecting this and reversing appropriately.

Comment: No, they don't. `\u10000` does **not** represent the character you think it does, it is a string of **two** characters: `{\u1000} and 0`, because you can use either **four or eight digits**. The fifth character, `0`, is not part of the unicode escape sequence (try `\u1000X`). Inspect the value of `s` to confirm.

Comment: You are right.  Am I alone in finding this a little confusing?  I still think a user would be stumped by this.  Is \u10000 a surrogate pair?

Comment: In my opinion it is not confusing. :) It enables you to use unicode characters in mid-sentence, just like your `Les Mise\u0301rables`. Where would the escape sequence stop when it is directly followed by valid hexadecimal digits (`\u1234a5c`)? Is `a5c` part of the unicode character, or part of the rest of the string?

Comment: I am seeing what you mean now.  Like in the cartoons when the lightbulb turns on above the characters head. :)

Answer (score 2):

Necromancing. 
This happens because you use `List<char>.Reverse` instead of `List<string>.Reverse`

```
// using System.Globalization;

TextElementEnumerator enumerator =
    StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator("Les Mise\u0301rables");

List<string> elements = new List<string>();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    elements.Add(enumerator.GetTextElement());

elements.Reverse();
string reversed = string.Concat(elements);  // selbarésiM seL
```

See Jon Skeet's pony video for more information:
https://vimeo.com/7403673

Here's how you properly reverse a **string** (a string, not a **sequence of chars**):

```
public static class Test
{

    private static System.Collections.Generic.List<string> GraphemeClusters(string s)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<string> ls = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

        System.Globalization.TextElementEnumerator enumerator = System.Globalization.StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s);
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            ls.Add((string)enumerator.Current);
        }

        return ls;
    }


    // this 
    private static string ReverseGraphemeClusters(string s)
    {
         if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || s.Length == 1)
              return s;

        System.Collections.Generic.List<string> ls = GraphemeClusters(s);
        ls.Reverse();

        return string.Join("", ls.ToArray());
    }

    public static void TestMe()
    {
        string s = "Les Mise\u0301rables";
        string r = ReverseGraphemeClusters(s);

        // This would be wrong:
        // char[] a = s.ToCharArray();
        // System.Array.Reverse(a);
        // string r = new string(a);

        System.Console.WriteLine(r);
    }
}
```

Note that you need to know the difference between 
- a character and a glyph
- a byte (8 bit) and a codepoint/rune (32 bit)
- a codepoint and a GraphemeCluster [32+ bit] (aka Grapheme/Glyph)

[Reference:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331819/whats-the-difference-between-a-character-a-code-point-a-glyph-and-a-grapheme)

> Character is an overloaded term than can mean many things.
>
> A code point is the atomic unit of information. Text is a sequence of
>   code points. Each code point is a number which is given meaning by the
>   Unicode standard.
>
> A grapheme is a sequence of one or more code points that are displayed
>   as a single, graphical unit that a reader recognizes as a single
>   element of the writing system. For example, both a and ä are
>   graphemes, but they may consist of multiple code points (e.g. ä may be
>   two code points, one for the base character a followed by one for the
>   diaresis; but there's also an alternative, legacy, single code point
>   representing this grapheme). Some code points are never part of any
>   grapheme (e.g. the zero-width non-joiner, or directional overrides).
>
> A glyph is an image, usually stored in a font (which is a collection
>   of glyphs), used to represent graphemes or parts thereof. Fonts may
>   compose multiple glyphs into a single representation, for example, if
>   the above ä is a single code point, a font may chose to render that as
>   two separate, spatially overlaid glyphs. For OTF, the font's GSUB and
>   GPOS tables contain substitution and positioning information to make
>   this work. A font may contain multiple alternative glyphs for the same
>   grapheme, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a start.  It might not be the fastest, but it does seem to work for what we have thrown at it.

```
internal static string ReverseItWithSurrogate(string stringToReverse)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    // We want to get the string into a character array first
    char[] stringArray = stringToReverse.ToCharArray();

    // This is the object that will hold our reversed string.
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool haveSurrogate = false;

    // We are starting at the back and looking at each character.  if it is a
    // low surrogate and the one prior is a high and not < 0, then we have a surrogate pair.
    for (int loopVariable = stringArray.Length - 1; loopVariable >= 0; loopVariable--)
    {
    // we cant' check the high surrogate if the low surrogate is index 0
    if (loopVariable > 0)
    {
        haveSurrogate = false;

        if (char.IsLowSurrogate(stringArray[loopVariable]) &&    char.IsHighSurrogate(stringArray[loopVariable - 1]))
       {
          sb.Append(stringArray[loopVariable - 1]);
          sb.Append(stringArray[loopVariable]);

         // and force the second character to drop from our loop
         loopVariable--;
         haveSurrogate = true;
       }

      if (!haveSurrogate)
      {
         sb.Append(stringArray[loopVariable]);
        }
       }
    else
    {
     // Now we have to handle the first item in the list if it is not a high surrogate.
      if (!haveSurrogate)
      {
        sb.Append(stringArray[loopVariable]);
       }
     }
   }

result = sb.ToString();
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best viewed NOT in Chrome!

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
namespace OrisNumbers
{
    public static class IEnumeratorExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> AsIEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerator iterator)
        {
            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return (T)iterator.Current;
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var s = "foo  bar mañana mañana" ;
            Debug.WriteLine(s);
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Join("", StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s.Normalize()).AsIEnumerable<string>().Reverse()));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```